# Connect to SQLServer with Pyodbc using Trusted Connection on OSX

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc, unixodbc

Is it possible connect using local Domain credentials that I use to log into my OSX System to connect to a SQLServer DB with python, pyodbc, unixodbc, and FreeTDS like I would when connecting from a Windows system?

Windows Connection String that works:

```
    pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver='FreeTDS', TDS_Version = 7.0, server='<SERVER>', port=<PORT>, database='<DATABASE>')
```

When I attempt this from a Mac I get the following error:

```
    pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am attempting to avoid hard coding usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trusted_Connection setting indicates whether to use Windows Authentication Mode for login validation or not. Given that you're using a Mac, I suspect that Windows Authentication Mode will not be possible and so it will be necessary to pass the username and password to the connection string.

Comment: This seems to be the case... I have scoured the net and tried a few different methods with no success.  Thank you.